# Which data structure to store tables and field names?

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, data-structures, dictionary

I am retrieving tables and their respective fields from a database, and would like to store them within my C# application.

The two storage options which I can think of are:

1. A `Dictionary` which uses the table's name as a key and a `List<string>` to store the fields.  Thus, something like this: `Dictionary<string, List<string>>`
2. A list within a list: `List<List<string>>`

What would be the better approach in terms of performance and best practice? Are there better options?

Thanks

Comment: The Data Structure will depend not only on the storage form factor of your Data but most importantly on the requirements you want to suffice with your Data. What are you going to do with those tables? Search, alter, export... That will provide necessary info to analyze which is a better approach.

Comment: Do you only need table and column names? Or datatypes as well? What about primary and foreign keys? Indices, other constraints? Only tables or views as well? I think you should take a look at the [`Information_Schema`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186778.aspx) views. You'll only need a subset of these but it's a good starting point.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I prefer (1), perhaps making things a bit more object oriented however:

```
public class DatabaseTable : List<string>
{

}

public class DatabaseTableRegistry : Dictionary<string, DatabaseTable>
{

}
```

Answer (score 2):

I'd look at the existing classes in the `System.Data` namespace and see if any of them match your requirements - ie: `DataColumn`, `DataTable`, etc.